# Working of rand() function in particular question?

Tags: c++

The range of the function is from 0 - 32767. We have to generate random numbers between this range and calculate the average of each number generated it would be exactly equal to 16383.5. And in this problem, we are required to find the smallest number of time Rand() function is called to produce average = 16383.5+-0.0001.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double x,avg = 0,n=1;
    while(n<=1000){
          x = (rand() % (32767 + 1 ) + 0) ;
          avg = x/n;
          if((avg == (16383.5+0.0001))||(avg == (16383.5-0.0001))){
          break;
          }
          n++;
    }
    cout<<n<<endl<<y<<endl;
}
```

It must print n as it can but I am not getting required ans. as avg never reaches that value. But why?

Comment: you're not computing the average at all. `x/n` give the **last** rand value divided by the number of values read. Unless you just happened to land on 16384 on the first rand, or 32767 on the second, all hope of getting within your sought range are gone. Consider what is missing... a *sum* perhaps ?

Comment: Hmm, I think let me try then I will share with you if it works.

Comment: It's still not working...

Comment: ```x = (rand() % (32767 + 1 ) + 0);
          sum += x;
          avg = sum/n;```

Comment: I'm just curious, why are you adding `0` in that expression?

Comment: You're looking for *exact* matches; that's not the assignment. You're supposed to be looking if the average is in a *range*, 16383.5 +/- 0.0001. Think about how that is different than what you're doing.

Comment: I think to take random values from range of 0 - 32767.

Comment: Can you write code for what you are saying @WhozCraig

Comment: Be aware that modulo calculation does not provide good distribution of random numbers. You usually get better distribution by `rand() * max / (RAND_MAX)` – provided `max` and `RAND_MAX` are small enough not to produce overflow.

Comment: Any concrete reason to stick with outdated `rand` function? C++'s new [random facilities](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution) are much better choice.

Comment: @Aconcagua: `% 32768` is equivalent to `& 0x7FFF` so it doesn't change the distribution. Also, the newer random facilities are not that much better as one would think, sadly. Like most of the new C++ stuff they look awesome at first but then turn out half-assed. MT sure isn't as poor as the traditional poor-tap LCG in `rand()`, but initializing it properly isn't trivial, and the provided funtions for doing so _look great_ but are actually very poorly implemented (esp. `std::seed_seq` and `std::random_device`). They're hardly better than `srand(time(0))`, sadly. Actually... worse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original post didn't compute any average because it didn't tally any sum to divide by `n`. No sum = no average computation. Further, your expression for break-checking is wrong. It's looking for exact matches of two values, your assignment is to wait until the result is within a *range* of 16383.5 +/- 0.0001. Finally, a minor point, you never seeded rand, so don't expect anything but the same answer repeatedly.

Doing this right (enough), is below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

int main()
{
    std::srand(static_cast<unsigned>(std::time(nullptr)));

    double sum = 0;
    int n = 1;
    for (;; ++n)
    {
        double x = std::rand() % 32768;
        sum += x;
        double avg = sum / n;
        if ((avg <= 16385.5 + 0.0001) && (avg >= 16383.5 - 0.0001))
            break;
    }
    std::cout << n << '\n';
}
```

**Sample Output**

```
351
```

Comment: Worth to be mentioned: `n` is not necessarily the same for every programme run, as `srand` is fed with different seeds...

Comment: Hm, just wondering: Some unlucky seed might produce 16385-n and 16385+n+1 or 16385-n+1 and 16385+n as first two elements of the sequence, producing output of n == 2...